# Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX) when pressing Ctrl-C in code editor

Tags: visual-studio-2012

this happens in visual studio 2012 when pressing Ctrl-C on any text or code.
it started happening after i installed Web Essentials Extension (although  i don't think it is  causing it)... even after removing it the error did not disappear.

any help is appreciated.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after immediately install "Productivity Power Tools 2012". Try to remove some extensions and see if works. Sorry for absence of details, this worked for me.